# Extra character in JSON

Tags: java, json

I parsed JSON as follows:

```
URL urlData = new URL("http://example.com/file.php");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                urlData.openConnection().getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String showtimes = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(showtimes);
```

But in the beginning of the string is inserted into the `?`:

> ?{"date":"19","error":false,...

As I understand it, this problem occurs because of encoding. If I remove the "UTF-8", a string looks like:

> п»ї{"date":"19","error":false,...

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the page you are loading is not encoded in UTF-8. Find out what encoding it uses and use that encoding in your app (or convert it to UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any encoding issues that would produce this output.

However, this might be designed to counter a security bug in some particular (older) browser versions.  Some browsers allowed you to define setters/getters for the generic `Object` and `Array` types - this meant that if you included the JSON file as a JavaScript script:

... then the setters/getters would be called, and you could extract the data - in violation of the cross-origin policy.

An up-to-date browser will not have this issue, but some sites still guard against this by prefixing their JSON data with a known string (to disrupt JavaScript evaluation).

If this is the case, then it *really should* be documented clearly in their API docs.

*(Link: [relevant Mozilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=376957))*

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be attempting to directly read from an HTTP url.  Unfortunately, unless you want to write a custom HTTP client parser this will cause problems.  My recommendation is to use a third party library specifically designed to read from HTTP urls. As encoding is a part of the HTTP response it will handle properly decoding the response from the server for you.

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/